# How to create dummy data to database when using Docker?

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker

I have a Django app running in Docker container. I'd like to populate my Postgres -database with some data when I run `docker-compose up`. I tried writing a sql -file:

```
# sql/fill_tables.sql

INSERT INTO person(name, gender)
    VALUES ('testUser', 'male');
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` where I have added the sql to the volumes:

```
db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./sql/fill_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/fill_tables.sql
    env_file: .env 
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=$DATABASE_NAME
      - POSTGRES_USER=$DATABASE_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$DATABASE_PASSWORD
    container_name: postgres_db
```

This however doesn't do anything, the table in my database stays empty. How is this supposed to be done with Docker?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with docker-compose.yml, the reason it is not working right now is probably because you already have some data in `/data`.

If the `/data` volume exists and has some data, it will not be overwritten by `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/fill_tables.sql`

I guess you could remove the line `./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data` from your docker-compose.yml to see your database being fulfilled by `fill_tables.sql`

Comment: I have no folder `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, should I create one manually? Do I create the folder inside my data/db/ or somewhere else? At the moment I have a folder called sql in my project folder and inside it the `fill_tables.sql` -file.

Comment: `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` is inside on your docker container your do not have to create it. Did you try to remove the `./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data` from `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Yes I tried that but the tables are not created and the app tells me I have not migrated my migrations. I guess I'd have to write a table creation sql also? Would prefer to just add some data to my  existing tables when I run the container up..

Comment: How did you generate your `fill_tables.sql` ? Did you export the data or did you make yourself ? I guess what you sould do first create your database and add the data and then export the your database in a `.sql `file. then replace your current `fill_tables.sql` by the new one.

Comment: I made it myself, it's just a test file to test if I can get something written into my database.

Comment: There is your issue. First export the database you have created then add the 
`INSERT INTO person(name, gender)
    VALUES ('testUser', 'male');` You got the solution of your first question, I guess.